# Is there a hotel in Vatican City?

Tags: italy, rome, vatican-city

I have seen several websites refer to the *Residenza Paolo VI Hotel* as inside Vatican City, but when I look at Google Maps it seems like it's just outside the borders, so actually in Italy.  Which is right?

Comment: I can't find the article anymore, but I am pretty sure that I a few months ago read somewhere about private apartment rentals for tourists within the Vatican City. On TripAdvisor, I can find at least one apartment allegedly in the Vatican City, but looking at the exterior photos of the surroundings, I am pretty sure that the claimed location of the apartment is fake.

Comment: Related to the title: There is a guesthouse in the Vatican, but really for "guests" of the Vatican, either permanent residents of the City or people coming for a meeting or a conference: http://www.catholicnews.com/services/englishnews/2013/pope-francis-to-live-in-vatican-guesthouse-not-papal-apartments.cfm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I checked out the location of Residenza Paolo VI Hotel on several sites, including the site of the hotel. Nowhere it is claimed to be in Vatican city, it is however claimed to be on St Peters Square.

According to Google maps that is right, just outside the Vatican city borders.
[Here is a link](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Residenza+Paolo+VI+Hotel/@41.9010732,12.4545668,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x132f60575713f4e5:0x6f3c3bd23584ddce!8m2!3d41.9010732!4d12.4567555) to the map.

More searching on booking.com does not result is hotels within Vatican city.
They place a marker on the middle of St Peter Square but when you follow the marker it is for an apartment rental site and non of the offered apartments are very close to the square, even less within Vatican city.

If there is a hotel within the boundaries of the Vatican City, I bet it is a private (church owned) one for visiting officials, not available for commercial trade. But as I only work from internet, I am not sure.

Comment: As far as I know, uninvited people can only enter the “public“ parts of Vatican City: the Basilica, the Audience Hall (with free ticket), the Musei Vaticani (paid ticket, includes the Sistine Chapel and the Raphael's rooms), the Gardens (paid guided visit). Access to all other parts is restricted. See http://www.vaticanstate.va/content/vaticanstate/en/informazioni-utili.html